# jsviews table dynamic column

Tags: hyperlink, html-table, jsviews

I'm trying to make a table with a columns array to enable which columns to show, but I want to be able to use link, but using it like I did below doesn't update using the obeservable setProperty.

What I currently ended up doing was first generating a template based on the columns collection and using that template to generate the table.

So I'd like to know is there a way to do this in a single template?

```
<table id="test"><tbody></tbody></table>
<script>
    var columns = [{field:"Id"}, {field:"Name"}];
    var data = {rows:[{Id:1, Name:"a", Bla:"bla"},{Id:2, Name:"b", Bla:"bla"}]};
    var tmpl = "{^{for rows}}<tr>{^{for ~columns}}<td>{^{:#parent.parent.data[field]}}</td>{{/for}}</tr>{{/for}}";

    $.templates(tmpl).link("#test tbody", data, { columns: columns });

    var d = $.view($("#test tbody tr")[0]).data;
    $.observable(d).setProperty("Name", "c");
</script>
```

Comment: There are a few ways to do that. But with the next update to JsViews you will be able to use DataMaps to solve that in a particularly powerful/elegant way. I'm planning to get back here with details soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach you can use:

```
<table id="test"><tbody></tbody></table>

<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="tmpl">
    {^{for rows}}
        <tr>
            {^{props}}
                {{if ~inColumns(key)}}
                    <td>{^{:prop}}</td>
                    <td><input data-link="prop"/></td>
                {{/if}}
            {{/props}}
        </tr>
    {{/for}}
</script>

<script>
    var columns = ["Id", "Name"];

    var data = {
        rows:[{Id:1, Name:"a", Bla:"bla"},{Id:2, Name:"b", Bla:"bla"}]
    };

    $.templates("#tmpl").link("#test tbody", data, {
        inColumns: function(key) {
            return $.inArray(key, columns) !== -1;
        } 
    });

    var d = $.view($("#test tbody tr")[0]).data;

    $.observable(d).setProperty("Name", "c");
</script>
```

With the next update, there will be a new DataMaps feature which will provide an alternative approach. I'll probably update this answer, once that is available.